# shell script,how to print the newline in default position always?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i am using `tput sc/rc/ed` and `printf '\E[n<A|B|C|D>'|printf '\E[y;xH'`,here two ex:

```sh
tty_esc(){ printf "\e[%s" "$1"; }
tty_cursor_locate(){ tty_esc "${2};${1}H"; }
tty_cursor_right(){ tty_esc ${1}C; }
```

```sh
print_center()
{
    local _width=$(tput cols)
    local _str=$1
    local _row=$2
    local _cols=$((((${_width} - ${#_str})) / 2))

    tty_cursor_locate ${_cols:-100} ${_row:-1}
    printf "%s\n" " ${_str} "
}
```

```sh
show_net_adapter()
{
    local _addr _iface _count
    local _origin=$1
    iface_line_count=

    tty_cursor_locate ${_origin:-0} 4
    printf "%s\n" "Current connected adapter(s):"
    for _iface in $(get_net_adapter);do
        if [[ "${_iface}" != "lo" ]];then
            _addr=$(get_net_addr ${_iface})
            test -z "${_addr}" && continue
            let _count+=1
            let iface_line_count+=1
            if [[ ${_count} != 1 ]];then
                unset _count
                printf '%s' "${tty_rever}"
            fi
            tty_cursor_right ${_origin:-0}
            print_fill 50 ${_iface} ${_addr:--}
            printf "${tty_reset}"
        fi
    done
    print_line -s "=" ${line_origin}
}
```

as above, I should locate the cursor before I print something.

BTW

I use `trap "myfunc" WINCH`, it only works once. when I try again to change my crt. size, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by `in default position always`, either intentations or overwrite the text but the following function can do both.

```
#!/bin/sh

preent () { # $1=indent start line, $2=spaces, $3=reset cursor, $4=update (1=itself, 2=delete previous lines, 0=newline), $5=save cursor, $6=text
    if text="$6""$7""$8""$9""${10}" awk -v col="$COLUMNS" -v cp="$_CURSOR_POS" -v id="$1" -v spc="$2" -v rc="$3" -v u="$4" -v sc="$5" '
    BEGIN { t=ENVIRON["text"]; lt=sprintf("%d",col/4); idx=1; len=length(t); y=0; sp=sprintf("% " spc "s",""); delete A;
        for(ln=1;idx<len;ln++) { if(ln==id) { col=col-spc; y=1 } bd=col-lt; f=0
            for(i=idx+col-1;i>bd;i--) { c=substr(t,i,1);
                if(c==" ") {
                    if(y) { A[ln]=sprintf("%s%s",sp,substr(t,idx,i-idx)); idx=i+1; f=1; break
                    } else { A[ln]=substr(t,idx,i-idx); idx=i+1; f=1; break }
                } else if(c=="") {
                    if(y) { A[ln]=sprintf("%s%s",sp,substr(t,idx,i-idx)); idx=i; f=1; break
                    } else { A[ln]=substr(t,idx,i-idx); idx=i; f=1; break; }
                }
            }
            if(!f) {
                if(y) { A[ln]=sprintf("%s%s",sp,substr(t,idx,col)); idx=idx+col
                } else { A[ln]=substr(t,idx,col); idx=idx+col }
            }
        } if(rc=="true") cp=0;
        if(u=="1") { for(i=1;i<ln;i++) printf("\x1B[1A\x1B[K"); cp=cp+1-i
        } else if(u=="2") { for(i=0;i<cp;i++) printf("\x1B[1A\x1B[K"); cp=0 }
        for(i=1;i<ln;i++) printf("%s\n",A[i]);
        if(sc=="true") { exit ln-1+cp } else { exit 0 }
    }'; then _CURSOR_POS="$?"; else _CURSOR_POS="$?"; fi
}
```

**Example 1 (Long text, 5 spaces indent, indent starts from 2nd line)**

```
preent 2 5 'false' 0 'false' 'You never say good-bye Handong-an monghani udukoni anja Dashi saenggakhatjiman ' \
'Momchul sun optkesso Ontong kudae saenggak hal subakke omnun ' \
"Nae jashini miwo Don't you let me go Baby don't you let me down"
```

**Output**

```
You never say good-bye Handong-an monghani
     udukoni anja Dashi saenggakhatjiman Momchul
     sun optkesso Ontong kudae saenggak hal
     subakke omnun Nae jashini miwo Don't you
     let me go Baby don't you let me down
```

**Example 2 (Long text with no spaces)**

```
preent 2 5 'false' 0 'false' 'Youneversaygood-byeHandong-anmonghaniudukonianjaDashisaenggakhatjiman' \
'MomchulsunoptkessoOntongkudaesaenggakhalsubakkeomnun' \
"NaejashinimiwoDon'tyouletmegoBabydon'tyouletmedown"
```

**Output**

```
Youneversaygood-byeHandong-anmonghaniudukonianjaD
     ashisaenggakhatjimanMomchulsunoptkessoOntong
     kudaesaenggakhalsubakkeomnunNaejashinimiwoDo
     n'tyouletmegoBabydon'tyouletmedown
```